# WPF datagrid: I want to tweak the style that applies in edit mode

Tags: wpf, datagridcell

My WPF application has a `DataGrid`, and there are `DataGridTextColumn` where users can input information. Then, I am asked to change the foreground or background color of a `DataGridCell` when some validation errors or something else occur. I took a more programmatic approach than a conservative MVVP design would require, and wrote some codes in C#, like.

```
cell.Background = Brushes.Pink;
cell.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
```

It worked pretty well, but my biggest problem is, while this coloring occurs during the time users are inputting characters, it's virtually hides by a style that seems to apply to cells in editing mode. It's neither an `IsSelected` style nor `IsFocused` style, if my understanding is right. Perhaps that's `EditingElementStyle`.

My question is how to change the color of the style that applies to when a cell is being edited, if temporarily? I tried `DataGridCell.SetCurrentValue()`, but little info is available...

P.S.
I know there are some straitfoward ways, like using `IDataErrorInfo`. For some reasons, it didn't work for my app, so I have to solve thing in another way.